# Write my own autopilot software

Tags: autopilot, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, software

For a hobbyist looking to write an autopilot program for a mode lUAV/drone, what are the aviation related considerations that would be involved in its design?  How could things like the ADC (air data computer), or pitot static system, be utilized to control bank angles and decent rates?  Are there any specific rules of thumb that would assist the autopilot in making smooth corrections?  For example, how should I calculate the max VSI in a climb or when approaching a level-off altitude, and is there a rule of thumb for bank angle in a turn?

Your answers will guide me in asking an educated question at the Programmers StackExchange and get programming specific advice on how to proceed.

Comment: This question appears to be primarily about programming, not aviation. It would be better suited on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DannyBeckett it would get closed as too broad on Programming, and off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unfortunately just because it's too broad for Stack Overflow doesn't mean it works well here, for many of the same reasons. The question is currently too broad because there are a lot of unaddressed assumptions, the biggest one being "How complex do you want the autopilot to be?" (a simple wing-leveler / altitude-hold? A GPS-interfaced autopilot that knows about airspace and will keep you from flying somewhere you shouldn't?) -- There are [RTCA standards](http://www.rtca.org/store_product.asp?prodid=1058) but buying those might be overkill, you won't know until you refine your mission scope.

Comment: I vote to reopen the question, just because its broad doesn't mean that there isn't a general answer.  He's looking for a general consensus, not *public static void main(String args) {}*.  He can then take his more refined question back to Stack Overflow once he's on the right track.

Comment: Personally, I would characterize the task as requiring three areas of expertise. First you're looking at the usual programming skills required for any real-time process control application, which means writing efficient interrupt-driven code. Second, a good applied mathematics capability will be most helpful in designing the algorithms that you're going to code. Third, a thorough understanding of how an airplane is controlled will be required. I am unaware of any single book that would supply all the necessary information. I doubt there would be much of a market for such a text.

Comment: I like the question in general, and would like to see it better scoped.

Comment: @Terry, For a very simple AP, I think you'd actually be writing event-driven code.  Rasberry Pi would probably work brilliantly in this case.  Depending on how many people are working on this project, one wouldn't need hardly any understanding of how an aircraft flies to write an API that someone could implement.  In reality, at its most basic, all it should do is process information taken from the ADC and call functions like moveStab(+/-x).  Once implemented it would just require a bit of tweaking to prevent oscillations and for stability.  I doubt it would have to be FAA compliant.

Comment: @SHAF Stack Overflow would not be the place for such a question. Stack Overflow deals with actual implementation problems, Programmers deals with whiteboard problems.

Comment: @raptortech97, Sure, edited as required.

Comment: The edited version of the question is still, essentially, "How does autopilot software work". That's still far too broad.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  I wonder if things like an ADC with pitot/static system would even be used on a small drone/UAV.  Those are pretty big and heavy components.  I am pretty sure most hobbyist level aircraft would want to use something based on MEMS sensors which are readily available.  Something small and light like these, http://www.o-navi.com/.  Here is a pre-packaged autopilot. http://www.feiyu-tech.com/product-en.php?id=26

Comment: I would look at industrial control systems - like PID controllers as a guiding method. PID control is a heavily simplified version of what's at the core of a tomahawk missile.